# How to solve ODEs with a parameter that changes over time.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, python

I have the following coupled ODEs:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dA}{dt} & = k_{1}\text{activity} - k_{2}A\\
\frac{dB}{dt} & = k_{3}A - k_{4}B
\end{cases}
$$
with $k_1 = 1.0, k_2 = 0.1, k_3 = 0.1, k_4 = 1$. The value of $\text{activity}$ changes over time and it can be randomly either $0$ or $1$. How can I solve it ? I am using the Python solve [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

P.S. In order to answer to the questions:

> Could you closer specify what "changes randomly over time" means? And
> what are the desired results from the simulation of this stochastic
> process?

For each point of the time, *activity* can be either 0 or 1. For example, if time is between 0 and 100 or, said in Pythonic words `time = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)`, *activity* is a numpy array that has the same length of `time` and with elements that are 0 or 1 (like `array(0,0,0,1,1,1,...)`).

As regards the desired results, I would like to obtain the trend of A and B over time in the situation that I have described.

Comment: Don't you have two cases based on activity? Why not solve each case? Also, the equations are decoupled, so you can solve for each of the two cases in the first equation and then substitute that into the second and solve.

Comment: Could you closer specify what "changes randomly over time" means? And what are the desired results from the simulation of this stochastic process?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have edited the post.

Comment: If the right hand side is random 0/1, then you have a *stochastic differential equation*. If the activity was a Gaussian, there may be an explicit solution for the expected value of $A(t),B(t)$ but I doubt that there is one for the 0/1 process. You will have to solve the ODE many times for different realizations of the activity and then compute the mean value of the computed solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much @WolfgangBangerth. It would be too much to ask you to do what you have just said in words step by step for this case ?

Comment: @HelpNeederStudent I'm not sure it's possible to do it step by step. My suspicion -- but please correct me -- is that you don't know what a stochastic ODE is. I can't explain that in a few simple steps, but there are good resources out there that explain that on 20 or 30 pages. Once you understand what these books/web sites/... are telling you, you will understand what I said above.

Comment: Yes your suspicion is right @WolfgangBangerth !

Comment: Note that for a time array from 0 to 100 with step size 1 you need `time = linspace(0,100,100+1)`, the last is the number of nodes, not segments. You can implement a piecewise constant function in the situation as given here as `act = activity[int(t)]`. `odeint` should work, perhaps not optimally, with this function on the right side.